# What does map() do?

Tags: arduino-uno

Regarding the following code:

```
mpu.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz); 
ax = map(ax, -17000, 17000, -1500, 1500);
```

I know the reason for taking 17000 as value - that's 1g.  But I am not getting how and why 1500 value is taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map()` function is well explained [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map).

In short, it maps one range of numbers to another.  In this case it will map `ax` from the range (-17000:17000) into the range (-1500:1500).

Imagine a ruler with both inches and cm on.  If you have a measurement in inches, you can represent that same measurement (point on the ruler) in cm.  Your "ruler" here has one scale ranging from -17000 to 17000, and another scale ranging from -1500 to 1500.  You're finding the reading on the second side at the point `ax` on the first.

If you mean specifically why are those numbers used -- then I have no idea since you give no context.

Comment: .Thanku so much. now i understood. your exampple of ruler just nailed it.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was helpful you can accept it and optionally up-vote it :-)